# pipe fail on gallery search

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

Hi I've done this filter pipe where I want to look for my imagename and my imageid from all my images, but it just looks for the name and id from the first image.
Anything is wrong on my code aparently.

```
This is my filter.pipe.ts class where I implement my search method 

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, arg: any): any {
    if (arg === '' || arg.length < 1) return value; 
    const resultPosts = [];
    for (const imagen of value) {
      if (imagen.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        resultPosts.push(imagen);
      }else if (imagen.imagenId.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1){
        resultPosts.push(imagen);
    };
    return resultPosts;
  }
  }
}


My list.component.html where I have my input for searching:


<div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"name="filterImagen" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="filterImagen"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  
  </form>
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let imagen of imagenes | filter:filterImagen; index as i"> 

//when I look for the imagename or imageid, it just looks if my first image has the name I write on the searchbar

      <div class="card mb-3 animated zoomIn">
            <h3 class="card-header">{{imagen.name}}</h3>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><b>ID: </b>{{imagen.imagenId}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body text-center">
            <img style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{imagen.imagenUrl}}" alt="Card image">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>

/* On my list.component.ts (here I just have a variable filter declared like: )*/

 imagenes: Imagen[] = [];
  
filterImagen = '';  //just declared it here
```

//I already imported my FormsModule on app.module.ts and my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to add the pipe to Declarations? Or better yet, export it from a module, and import that module into the app.module?

UPDATE - I see your error :)
You have to move `return resultPosts` out of the for-loop.

If you're interested, I refactored the pipe for clarity:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { Imagen } from "./app.component";

@Pipe({
  name: "filter"
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Imagen[], arg: any): any {
    if (arg === "" || arg.length < 1) return value;

    return value.filter(imagen => imagen.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
        imagen.imagenId.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  }
}
```